# Could you tell me the difference between 'study' and 'do a study'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw the sentence like 'The company did another study to find out the reason'.
Maybe I think that this sentence is transferred to 'The company studied to find out the reason.'

What is the difference between 'study' and 'did a study'?

Comment: Did you look up the definitions of the noun **study**?

Answer (score 1):

> to study

is to learn material either formally at a school or informally on one's own

> to do a study

is to perform research or an experiment usually to test an idea or hypothesis,

and incase there might be any confusion

> to do studying = to study

Answer (score 1):

The verb ***to study*** on its on own simply means to look into an issue. It becomes much more formal when you ***undertake***, ***do***, ***perform***, or ***conduct*** a study. This implies that you are going through a rigorous process and likely going to produce a document or otherwise report on the results.

Here are two examples using both:

> We wanted ***to conduct a study*** on early childhood education in order ***to study*** the effects of recess on learning outcomes.
> Let's get together and ***study*** the night before the exam, especially that legal case where the hospital ***performed a study*** without informing their patients.